# What is the difference between projective space and projective plane?

Tags: differential-geometry

May I know the difference between projective plane and a projective space?

I thought these two are same. But I have some doubts.

Thanks.

Comment: Without giving us the definitions that *you* are working with,  it's difficult for us to determine the source of your doubts.

Comment: To me, the *anything* plane is the $2$-dimensional case of the *anything* space.

Comment: Yea, that is for 2D, but what is happening if the space is 3D?

Answer (score 3):

The projective plane is the projective space of dimension $2$. There is a [projective space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_space) for every dimension $n\in\mathbb N$.